Delegating Session Factory Spring Integration Thread-Safe
I'm using Spring Integration to handle sftp session, I've noticed that in order to use multiple session and switch between them at runtime I have to use DelegatingSessionFactory and its method setThreadKey.
This method is thread-safe?
If not What is the correct way to implement it, ensuring thread safety?
Example:
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
  return IntegrationFlow
          .from("uploadFile")
          .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(delegatingSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.IGNORE)
                  .remoteDirectory("/upload")
                  .fileNameGenerator(message -> String.format("my_xml_%s.xml", LocalDateTime.now())))
          .get();
}

@Bean
public DelegatingSessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> delegatingSessionFactory() {
  Map<Object, SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry>> factoryMap = new HashMap<>();
  for (UsersProperties.User user : usersProperties.getUsers()){
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(false);
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    factory.setHost(user.getHost());
    factory.setPort(user.getPort());
    factory.setUser(user.getUsername());
    factory.setPassword("");
    factoryMap.put(user.getKey(),factory);
  }
  DefaultSessionFactoryLocator<SftpClient.DirEntry> factoryLocator = new DefaultSessionFactoryLocator<>(factoryMap);
  return new DelegatingSessionFactory<>(factoryLocator);
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class SftpServiceImpl implements SftpService {
    private final UploadMessagingGateway uploadMessagingGateway;
    private final DelegatingSessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> delegatingSessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void loadSftp(byte[] bytes, String filename, SftpThreadKey threadKey) {
        delegatingSessionFactory.setThreadKey(threadKey);
        uploadMessagingGateway.uploadFile(bytes, filename, threadKey);
        log.info("File uploaded: {}", filename);
        delegatingSessionFactory.clearThreadKey();
    }
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface UploadMessagingGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "uploadfile")
    void uploadFile(byte[] xmlByte,
                    @Header("filename") String filename,
                    @Header("sftpThreadKey") SftpThreadKey threadKey);

}


What you show is done as a normal call stack in the same thread. So, whatever you set via delegatingSessionFactory.setThreadKey(threadKey); is going to be available in the DefaultSessionFactoryLocator when it is called from that Sftp.outboundAdapter(). Even if you call that uploadFile() concurrently, every its call is going to happen in its own thread and whole your flow will be in respective scope.
You also can take a look into the ContextHolderRequestHandlerAdvice: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/handler-advice/context-holder.html#page-title
